# the actionListener or action in commandButton does not work after the usage of an ajax target

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```html
 <f:view>
            <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" header=" Enregistrer une nouvel nouvelle Structure d'attache " hideEffect="explode" showEffect="explode" modal="true">
                <h:form id="formAjouter" >
                     <p:panelGrid id="panelAjouter" columns="2">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Département:" />       
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="depart" value="#{structureBean.idDepartement}" label="programme"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:220px">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectioner le département" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                    <f:selectItems var="custe1" value="#{structureBean.listDepartement}"   itemLabel="#{custe1.intituleDepartement}" itemValue="#{custe1.id}" itemLabelEscaped="true" />
                                    <p:ajax listener="#{structureBean.changeListArr()}" event="change" process="@form" update="arrond"/>
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Arrondissement:" />       
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="arrond" value="#{structureBean.idArrondissement}" label="programme"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:220px">
                                    <f:selectItems var="custe2" value="#{structureBean.listArrondissement}"   itemLabel="#{custe2.intituleArrondissement}" itemValue="#{custe2.id}" itemLabelEscaped="true" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                 <p:outputLabel value="Categorie de Structure:" />       
                                 <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{structureBean.idCategorieStructure}" label="programme"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:220px">
                                     <f:selectItems var="custe3" value="#{structureBean.listCategorieStructure}"   itemLabel="#{custe3.intituleCategorieStructure}" itemValue="#{custe3.id}" itemLabelEscaped="true" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Intitule :" for="intitule" />
                                <p:inputText id="intitule" value="#{structureBean.structureAttache.intituleStructure}" title="intitulé" />
                                <p:outputLabel value="Code/Abréviation :" for="abrev" />
                                <p:inputText id="abrev" value="#{structureBean.structureAttache.codeStructure}" title="abrev"/>
                                <h:inputHidden id="number" value="#{structureBean.structureAttache.id}" />
                                <p:commandButton value="Enregistrer" action="#{structureBean.createStructure()}"  oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide()" update=":tableForm:table" id="bout" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
```

hi to all of you have been through a brainstorming for a long while, here is my problem. the actionListener or action in commandButton does not work after the usage of an ajax target. there is no issues meaning that the method called in the action listener is not even launch. actually I'm using two "oneMenu" with the second one populated according to the choice made in the first the I have a commandButton to validate the form but when I clic on the button nothing happen though when. I found this way of doing on the Primefaces web site. I tested a lot of option without success

Answer (score 0):

Try to minimize your code step by step to reduce the possible causes. For example, be sure that at least one of your selectOneMenu is working before you go on to the next like...

```
<p:panelGrid id="panelAjouter" columns="2">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Département:" />       
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="depart" value="#{structureBean.idDepartement}" label="programme"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:220px">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectioner le département" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                    <f:selectItems var="custe1" value="#{structureBean.listDepartement}"   itemLabel="#{custe1.intituleDepartement}" itemValue="#{custe1.id}" itemLabelEscaped="true" />
                                    <p:ajax listener="#{structureBean.changeListArr()}" event="change" process="@form" update="arrond"/>
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                <!--p:outputLabel value="Arrondissement:" />       
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="arrond" value="#{structureBean.idArrondissement}" label="programme"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:220px">
                                    <f:selectItems var="custe2" value="#{structureBean.listArrondissement}"   itemLabel="#{custe2.intituleArrondissement}" itemValue="#{custe2.id}" itemLabelEscaped="true" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                 <p:outputLabel value="Categorie de Structure:" />       
                                 <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{structureBean.idCategorieStructure}" label="programme"  filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:220px">
                                     <f:selectItems var="custe3" value="#{structureBean.listCategorieStructure}"   itemLabel="#{custe3.intituleCategorieStructure}" itemValue="#{custe3.id}" itemLabelEscaped="true" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Intitule :" for="intitule" />
                                <p:inputText id="intitule" value="#{structureBean.structureAttache.intituleStructure}" title="intitulé" />
                                <p:outputLabel value="Code/Abréviation :" for="abrev" />
                                <p:inputText id="abrev" value="#{structureBean.structureAttache.codeStructure}" title="abrev"/>
                                <h:inputHidden id="number" value="#{structureBean.structureAttache.id}" />
                                <p:commandButton value="Enregistrer" action="#{structureBean.createStructure()}"  oncomplete="PF('dlg').hide()" update=":tableForm:table" id="bout" /-->
                    </p:panelGrid>
```

Comment: I tested the same code without the ajax and it worked but my second oneMenu is populated with all items in the table "Arrondissement" wheras I would like only some elements that selected according to the choice made in the first oneMenu

Comment: I also want to insist on the fact that it looks like the action listener is not even launched because the is no error in my IDE(netbeans)